# Intercept checkbox change event in VueJS

Tags: checkbox, vue.js, radio-button, vuejs2

I have a long set of checkboxes. I would like two groups of three of them to behave as radio buttons. Now, leaving aside my UX choices, how can I make this work?

The checkboxes are implemented as properties on a single object, `layer`:

```js
data() {
  return {
    layer: {},
  }
},
watch: {
  layer: {
    handler(val, oldval) {
      mapping.updateLayers(val)
    },
    deep: true,
  },
},
```

That works fine. But intercepting `val` and updating `this.layer` inside `handler()` doesn't:

```js
handler: function(val, oldval) {
  if (val.FutureYear) { this.layer.NextYear = false; this.layer.ExistingYear = false; }
  if (val.ExistingYear) { this.layer.NextYear = false; this.layer.FutureYear = false; }
  if (val.NextYear) { this.layer.ExistingYear = false; this.layer.FutureYear = false; }
  mapping.updateFoiLayers(val);
},
```

How can I achieve this result? (I'd prefer not to have to implement actual radio buttons because that makes managing all the layers and UI more complex.)

Comment: One possible problem is that you didn't set an initial value to `layer`. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods. `When a Vue instance is created, it adds all the properties found in its data object to Vue’s reactivity system.` `It should be noted that properties in data are only reactive if they existed when the instance was created. `

Comment: That part works fine - that's what the `deep: true` is for.

Answer (score 8):

Example: https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/NyRJLW?editors=0010

The main problem is the logic in `watch`.

If FutureYear is selected already, other field becomes unchangeable. Because `if (val.FutureYear)` is always the first one being triggered and the other 2 field will always be set to false immediately.

Another thing about `watch` is that it will be triggered when

- user changed the value
- program changed the value (this is unnecessary and make things harder to handle)

Therefore, handling `@change` event is more appropriate in this scenario.

JS

```
methods: {
    handleChange: function(e) {
      const name = e.target.name;
      if (this.layer[name]) {
        Object.keys(this.layer).map((key)=>{
          if(key != name) {
            this.layer[key] = false;
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

html

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox"/ v-model="layer.FutureYear" name="FutureYear"  @change="handleChange($event)">FutureYear<br/>
  <input type="checkbox"/ v-model="layer.NextYear" name="NextYear"  @change="handleChange($event)">NextYear<br/>
  <input type="checkbox"/ v-model="layer.ExistingYear" name="ExistingYear"  @change="handleChange($event)">ExistingYear<br/>
 </div>
```